# How does <Plug> work in Vim?

Tags: vim

I didn't understand what `<Plug>` does and how to use it. I read the [documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#%3CPlug%3E) but it is not clear to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<Plug>` is just a special, synthetic key that is never actually sent by the keyboard; i.e. you cannot type it.

With this, the `:map` functionality that comes from old vi can be used as an abstraction layer for plugins.

Instead of directly mapping plugin functionality to a fixed key, plugins define a `<Plug>PluginNameFunctionName` mapping, which can then be freely remapped to the desired key by the user. As Vim allows to check for existing mappings (via `hasmapto()`), plugins can also define a default mapping if none was specified by the user.

#### TL;DR

- for your own personal mappings, you can ignore `<Plug>`
- if you use a plugin and need to customize its mappings, `:map` your own left-hand side to the `<Plug>`-mapping(s) provided by the plugin
- if you write a plugin, enable user customization as described in `:help using-<Plug>`